# TUIO touch events to WM_TOUCH and WM_GESTURE within an application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, touch, tuio

I am working on a winform application that receives TUIO touch events. These touch events are not processed natively by Windows, therefore do not show up as WM_TOUCH messages in the WndProc.

What mechanism can I use to inject the touch events so that they not only show up in WndProc as WM_TOUCH messages but also go through the components that produce  the WM_GESTURE messages?

I examined the Windows/Docs/Touch Input documentation but it didn't help me much as it assumes that low level events come from the device driver and events are used throughout the whole system.

For WPF applications I could achieve the required behavior using the `TouchDevice` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [TouchInjector](https://github.com/michaelosthege/TouchInjector) to make Windows process TUIO touch events like events from a HID touch devices.

Comment: Wow! 4 years passed, I moved on. Regardless, your answer is valid and useful. Thank you for caring.